# Give iPhone archive to distributor

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, distribution, archive

I've developed an application for an extern distributor. Now, they want to publish the application.
I decided to create an *xcarchive* of the complete app with Xcode. But I have problems with the bundle identifier. Have I to choose an identifier and the distributor creates the *provisiong profile* and the *certificate*?

Would be great if you can tell me what I have to look for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using xCode 4 (or above ) for this.

You're going to want to open your scheme editor (The drop down menu next to the 'Run' and 'Stop' button contains this). Select the 'Archive' scheme and make sure that it's building a release (or distribution ) copy of your app and not a debug version.

The speculative part of the question, it's probably different for each distributor, I'm assuming your distributor is already set up as an iOS Developer (ie they can distribute on the app store already) I just set the bundle identifier to something appropriate com.nameOfDistributor.nameOfApp.
In xCode 4 you don't need to worry about any provisioning profiles etc, or certificates, just archive that up and send it to the distributor. Just send them a note of what the bundle ID was, and they should be able to do all the code signing in xCode themselves if they're using xCode 4 that is.

If the distributor is unhappy with that they usually just email us back and we sort it out. But just archive the release build of the app and send it to them letting them know what you used as a bundle id (also let them know the version number if you've been incrementing that as development has progressed).

Comment: Thank you! But when I want to archive the app, this error is showing up: CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'. What's wrong? I just followed your instructions.

Comment: @Jamie This is not working. Same issue as paul said. Efelton has given valid answer

Answer (score 5):

Your Distributor needs to have a "Company" Apple Developer Account.

They invite you to their organization as a "Member"

You accept their invitation.

the next time you login to developer.apple.come you will be presented with a Team droplist (your team and their team)

Select Their team.

Now, go to the iOS provisioning Portal->Certificates. Generate a Developer Certificate. they will have to approve this, so let them know the request is coming.

Once you have a Developer Certificate they will need to make\modify a Developer Provisioning Profile, with your certificate enabled in the Profile, for the AppID in question.

Once this Profile is created you download it.

Now you have their Full Bundle ID (the GUID and the "com.customer.app")

Now you change Code Sign Identity for Release to "iPhone Developer".

You Build and Archive the app using the Developer Provisioning Profile.

In the Organizer you will see the app you just built, right-click on the app and do a "show in finder".

Zip up the .XCARCHIVE file and send it to your Distributor.

They will unzip and double-click on the .XCARCHIVE file, this will import it into their XCode's Organizer.

From Organizer they can ReSign the app for "iPhone Distribution" using the same Bundle ID that was used to compile the app.

They can distribute it as they see fit.